# Preload data in reactjs component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, reactjs-flux, flux

I'm creating simple application in **reactjs**/**flux** way.
I have **MessageStore** and **UserStore** that contain this data:

`MessageStore` contains

```
[
    {"id": 1, "text": "It is a test message", "userId": 155123}
]
```

`UserStore` contains

```
[
    {"id": 155123, "name": "Thomas Brown", "age": 35}
]
```

I'm creating component to display message. It needs **user name**, but it only has **userId** obtained from `props`.

Currently I use the [initial-ajax-like approach](https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/initial-ajax.html) to get this data (*warn: es6 react syntax*):

```
componentDidMount() {
    var author = UserStore.getById(this.props.userId);
    this.setState({
        author: author
    })
}
render() {
    return (<a>{this.state.author.name</a>);
}
```

**Is it correct?** I figured out that in this case `render` function **is called twice**. **Is there any other approach to do this?** Rendering loading icon? Avoid rendering before data is retrieved?

Comment: Is what correct? `render` will be called once during the initial pass and then again when you update the `state`. If you don't like that pattern, you'd need to preload the data **before** creating your component.

Comment: @WiredPrairie does **before** also includes **getIntitialState** call?

Comment: I'm suggesting you could not create your component in whatever container normally hosts the component.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One should move the

```
var author = UserStore.getById(this.props.userId);
return({
    author: author
})
```

part to getInitialState LifeCycle.

getInitialState is called exactly once for each instance of the component, here you get a chance to initialize the custom state of the instance. Unlike getDefaultProps this method is called once each time an instance is created. At this point you have access to this.props.